# Select pixel in WinForms PictureBox PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I develop a program with PowerShell and the assembly Windows Forms like the standard paint. I can load images and edit it, but I want to add a new tool: After clicking on the picture, I want to display the co-ordinates of the selected pixel in a TextBox.

[image: A section of my program window.]

The problem is how to get the co-ordinates from the selected pixel?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PictureBox` class inherits [a `MouseClick` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) you can subscribe to:

```
$pictureBox.add_MouseClick({
  param($sender, $mouseEventArgs)

  Write-Host "PictureBox was clicked at location $($mouseEventArgs.Location)"
})
```

Comment: Is there a subject you don’t know or can’t figure out right away? :P